# Using FIML (Full Information Maximum Likelihood) for simple correlation test on data with missings?

Tags: r, correlation, missing-data, lavaan

I have a dataset with missing values. Since my main hypothesis is just a simple regression, my adviser told me to use FIML regression. So I used lavaan package:

```
reg.model <- sem("Var1 ~ Var2 + Control", data=data, missing="ml.x")
```

This works great, but for an exploration, I'll have to do some correlation tests on the same dataset I used for the regression.
Since I am told to use FIML as missing treatment for correlation tests as well, I tried to use `corFiml(data.matrix, covar = FALSE, show=FALSE)` from psych package, but it doesn't provide p-values for significance testing.
Is there another way to use FIML for correlation test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a bivariate (simple, 1-predictor-only) regression, the standardized regression coefficient is equal to the bivariate product-moment correlation, so you could easily get the correlation with FIML in lavaan by looking at the STD.ALL column in the output of your bivariate regression analysis.